# how to ask user to input again and again after every invalid input

Tags: java

so my own valid dates only are from 1520 to 3999 and im new to this site and im new to java
please help
i want to know what did i do wrong or what to do in this code.

```
    int x;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.print ("Enter a date ");
        x = in.nextInt();
    }
    while (x<1520&&x>3999);
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
        System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop, get another integer whenever the input was invalid. Also, you need to change `&&` to `||` in your while condition, as no number is both less than 1520 and greater than 3999. You also do not need the `do` section, and you need to remove the semicolon after your while loop - it was preventing the loop from doing anything productive for you.

```
int x;
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print ("Enter a date ");
x = in.nextInt();

while (x<1520 || x>3999) // change this to "or", i.e. && --> || 
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
        System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
        x = in.nextInt(); // get another number before checking conditions again
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user in a while loop until he enters the correct date.

```
int x;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print ("Enter a date ");
        x = in.nextInt();
     while (x<1520||x>3999)
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
        System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
x = in.nextInt();
    }
}}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `;` after the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` operator is logical `AND`

Input value cannot be less than 1520 AND greater than 3999.
I think you want to check if `x` is less than 1520 OR greater than 3999.

To achive this you should use proper logical operator, in this case it is `OR`

`x<1520 || x>3999`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follows (note, I changed the && to an ||, because there is no number that is both greater than 3999 AND less than 1520.)

```
    int x;

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a date ");
    x = in.nextInt();


    while (x < 1520 || x > 3999)
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
        System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
        x = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `;` after the `while` condition.